# Strange UITextField(only) constraints behaviour on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a really strange constraints behaviour on iPad. It looks like:

[image]

As you can see here ALL elements on the canvas has the same `leading` and `trailing` values. But how you can see, the `button` and `labels` are correct but `textFields`. So ONLY textFields constraints are very strange and I cannot fix that. What can be wrong and how can I fix it? I have no idea. Maybe you could help me

[image]

Save button trailing constraint
[image]

Comment: can you screenshot all constraints , or share a demo to github

Comment: @Sh_Khan I've added a trailing constraint of the button. I guess it should help